# How to handle new popped up browser window with JAVA Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating the steps in a browser based application using Selenium and Java.
The issue which I am facing is, when I put the URL on the browser it would open a new window for authentication. 
I have tried different codes but none worked. I've also tried the code below in vain:

```
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) { 
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window) 
}
```

Comment: Need a screenshot of the "popped up browser window".  It sounds like an "alert' and not a popup from what you explain.

Comment: have you tried printing the window id or checking the number of windows to make sure that there are actually other windows and it's not some iframe or alert rather?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is an alert with authentication.
You can handle it as using *http://username:password@yourWebsiteURL.com* instead of *yourWebsiteURL.com* while trying to access your webpage